# Apollo Client - Possible to refetch only a fragment of a larger query when it's variables change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I wanted to explore the pattern of fetching all the needed data for a page in one request.  So let's say I have a user config page, which needs a list of teams to assign a user to, and a list of roles a user can have.  I'm using the following query to get the first page of users as well as all available roles and teams.

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

const listUser = gql`
  fragment listUser on Query {
    users(page: $page, per: $per) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          title
          avatar
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        count
      }
    }
  }
`;

const roleFragment = gql`
  fragment roleFragment on Query {
    roles {
      name
      id
    }
  }
`;

const teamsFragment = gql`
  fragment teamsFragment on Query {
    teams {
      nodes {
        id
        name
        manager {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const getUserConfig = gql`
  query getUserConfig($page: Int, $per: Int) {
    ...listUser
    ...roleFragment
    ...teamsFragment
  }
  ${listUser}
  ${roleFragment}
  ${teamsFragment}
`;
```

And I'm using it like this (generated using graphql-codegen):

```
const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useGetUserConfigQuery({
 variables: {
   page: 1,
   per: 7,
  }
});
```

This works really well and allows me to grab the data I need for the page in one round trip.  However, whenever I change the page variable for users (to go to the next page obviously), it's going to refetch **everything**.  Is there a way of doing this so that it only refetches the fragment that's variables changed?  Or is there a better pattern for what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the useQuery hook, you can query the initial data directly using [ApolloClient.query method](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#ApolloClient.query) directly, and then in subcomponents of your page subscribe to updates on subsets of your data [ApolloClient.watchQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#ApolloClient.watchQuery)

You can view example code for a range of different ApolloClient methods [here](https://github.com/ahrnee/graphql-codegen-hasura/blob/master/demo/src/autogen/hasura/ts.ts).